# PHP's mail() with "To:" in header

Tags: php, email

In PHP's official manual, for mail function an example is given like:

```
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com';
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
..
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

What's difference between giving recipient's email address in header vs in $to above? Which one should i use?

Comment: Please refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score -1):

$to is addresses will be sended to smtp server for mail. 
$headers[] it is owner of mail address. If you don't know the names of owners this mail, may be many mail servers will be detected you message like spam